# Getting NaN Error and undefined Error

Tags: javascript, html, json, string, numbers

I have a Problem with my push function in JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var myArr = []
            var len = myArr.length
            $.getJSON('daten.json', function(data) {

                    $.each(data,function(key,value) {

                         for(var i = 0; i <= len; i++){

                           myArr.push("<p>" + value.Name+i ,"&nbsp;", value.Nachname+i + "</p>")

                         }
                   })       
                $('.content').html(myArr.join(''))               
            })      
</script>
```

I need to convert `value.Name+i` like this = `value.Name0`, `value.Name1` and so on. I got a JSON File and the Keys are Dynamic, so the first entry got `Name0` the second `Name1` and so on. Now I must print the JSON file on my html page, but how I can write this line:

```
myArr.push("<p>" + value.Name+i ,"&nbsp;", value.Nachname+i + "</p>")
```

with my var `i` which increment in the loop, to call the Keys in my JSON file?
Like `value.Name0`. Doing `value.Name+i` and `value.Name.i` does not work.

Comment: You've not provided the data you're operating on, so how can we know what you need? It sounds like maybe you're saying you need `value["Name" + i]` in order to get the properties named `Name0`, `Name1`, etc, but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: How about give a sample example of the JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me what you're looking for is something like this:

```
myArr.push("<p>" + value['Name'+i] ,"&nbsp;", value['Nachname'+i] + "</p>")
```

This portion of javascript is covered pretty nicely here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert your i (integer value) to string prior to adding it.

use:

```
value.Name + i.toString()
```

here's the jfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/kpqmp49o/

Answer (score -1):

Take the object property in a variable, use condition to check if it has value or not then concat it

```
var nameval = value.name;
```

then use in your javascript variable

```
nameval+i
```